# image and text as value of content property

Tags: css

I'm using the `content:` property to give content to pseudo-elements.

I know I can give it an image value with `content:url(image.svg);` and text with content:"Hello";`, but how do I give a image and a text value. Display the image left of the text?

Comment: use `:before` for the image and `:after` for the text

Comment: Using CSS? have you tried something like .myImg:after{content:"Hello";}.myImg{content:url(image.svg);}

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Comment: @Oxymoron content doesn't work on real elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:after` and `:before` for add image and text.

look at this code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/4/)

```
div{
    background:#999;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
}
div:after{
    content:"Text is here";
    background:#ddd;
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    bottom:-20px;
    right:-20px;
}
div:before{
    content:url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20);
    background:#ddd;
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    bottom:-20px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for a solution later, just add both url() and "String" with a space between to the content of before:: pseudo-element.

```css
a::before {
  content: url("https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/favicon.ico") " EXTRA TEXT AFTER THE ICON: ";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/">Mozilla Home Page</a>
```

CSS documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Image_combined_with_text

As an alternative you can use content and background combination:

```css
a::before {
      content:" EXTRA TEXT AFTER THE ICON: ";
      background: url("https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/favicon.ico") no-repeat center left;
      padding-left: 35px;
    }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/">Mozilla Home Page</a>
```