# Image sizing rule not applied when defining in scss file but works in html tag

Tags: html, css, sass

I am new to SCSS and frontend development in general. I have this simple rule defined in a `.scss` file.

```
.header-logo {
  content: url('/assets/logo/logotype-blue.png'); 
  height : 40px; 
}
```

My goal is to have a class containing my header image so I can use it on every header in different pages.
The problem is when I use that rule like this:

```
 <img class="header-logo" alt="logo"/>
```

The image is rendered but the `height` constraint is not applied.

When I remove the class to have something like this:

```
 <img src="/assets/logo/logotype-blue.png" height="40" alt="logo"/>
```

The `height` constraint is well applied. I am a bit confused, some explanations would be very helpful.

Comment: Try `width: auto;`  and set height after that in SCSS. Or maybe `width: 100%` could also work. I am also wondering the solution :)

Comment: I tried both but same result. What I did is:   `.header-logo {
  content: url("/assets/logo/logotype-blue.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}`

Comment: I also made some research but couldn't find anything that make sense. Maybe use `src` attribute instead of adding image with `content` property. 
something like this. `<img src="/assets/logo/logotype-blue.png" class="header-logo">` and apply  `header-logo` class without `content`.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to avoid that approach. My goal is that if a day I have to change the image I will do it in one place (the .scss file).

Comment: So you can use `backgrond-image` property instead of `content`. It would work I think. 
I don't see much that `content` approach so much. `background-image` seems more common approach. 
`content` is usually handy when using `::before` or `::after` .

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027814/image-and-text-as-value-of-content-property and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browser and also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977957/can-i-change-the-height-of-an-image-in-css-before-after-pseudo-elements 

so much this :)

Comment: @Muhammedogz I tried several possibilities but none works :( !

Answer (score 0):

try a class like this on a Div element, not img tag.

```
.sizeMe{
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    background-image:  url('/assets/logo/logotype-blue.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: Why I have to use a div? Why this `<img src="/assets/logo/logotype-blue.png" height="40" alt="logo"/>` works wihtout using a div element?